# Can I use mortar to fill channels in a concrete floor?

Tags: concrete, central-heating, mortar

I recently had central heating installed in my 2 bedroom ground floor maisonette. We installed all the pipes in the channels which we dug in the concrete floor. I have covered all the pipes with insulation and now it is the time for refilling the channels and then covering all the floor with laminate/wood flooring.

I have cut some pipe insulation and fit them to the pipe just to keep some space for expansion and contraction; I am planning to put some sand (dried sand used for driveways) in the channels, say 2cm, and then fill them up with mortar.

My question is can I use mortar to fill the channels?

Comment: I hope you didn't put insulation on *top* of the pipes, between them and the finished floor…

Answer (score 1):

How wide are the channels? Mortar is ok for smaller areas less than 3/4" any bigger than this I would want to use fine aggregate cement (not just sand as in Mortar).